# I am trying to read a file into an Array and code wont output. I believe it has something to do with how im reading the file

Tags: arrays, c

I am trying to read a file where the first line tells the size of the array and the second line is the array elements separated by a tab. From this even will be sorted in ascending order first in a new array and odds followed in descending. So far I can't get it to output. Can anyone help?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int evenArray[20];
  
    int oddArray[20];
  
    int n;

    FILE *fp = fopen("array.txt","r");

    if(fp == NULL){
          return 0;
      }
        fscanf(fp,"%d\n",&n);
        
        int array[n];
        
        int i;
        
        int countOdd = 0;
        
        int countEven = 0;
        
        //Scans the Doc and inputs the numbers
        for(i = 0;i<n;i++)
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%d\t", &array[i]);
              if(array[i] % 2 == 0){
                    evenArray[countEven] = i;
                    countEven++;
                  }
                  else{
                      oddArray[countOdd] = i;
                      countOdd++;
                    }
        }
        fclose(fp);
        
        int final[n];
        
        ascendingInsertionSort(evenArray,countEven);
        
        descendingInsertionSort(oddArray,countOdd);
        
        int j;
        
        for ( j = 0; j < countEven; j++ ) {
              final[ j ] = evenArray[j];
           }
        
        int k;
        
        for ( k = countEven-1; k < n; k++ ) {
                 final[ k ] = oddArray[k];
              }
        
        int l;
        
        for (l = 0; l < n; l++ ) {
            printf("Element[%d] = %d\n", l, final[l] );
         }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Does the `fopen` succeed? What's in the input file? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: I am curious if it is intentional that your evenArray and oddArray contain indexes to the array as opposed to the actual even and odd values.